# I want to click the button in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am a beginner and non-technical person, I am completely stuck here

I want to click the New Project button using VBA

Here is the inspect Element for New project button
    `<button tabindex="0" class="xui-button xui-button-create xui-button-small" type="button" data-automationid="project-modal-new-button">New project</button>`

Below is the code, I have created so far, it's running without any issues and it will take me to the project tab from the Project Tab I need to click the new Project Button using VBA

```
Sub Xero()

Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set i = New InternetExplorer
i.Visible = True
i.navigate ("https://login.xero.com/")
Do While i.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set idoc = i.document
idoc.all.UserName.Value = "XXXXX"
idoc.all.Password.Value = "123"

Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each ele In eles
    If ele.ID = "submitButton" Then
    ele.Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Else
    End If
Next ele

i.navigate ("https://projects.xero.com/?CID=!QhJgj")

Do While i.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

End Sub
```

I want to click the New project button to move further

Answer (score 0):

Try using a css class selector (same idea as `getElementsByClassName` but faster)

```
While i.Busy Or i.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + Timeserial(0,0,2)
i.document.querySelector(".xui-button-create").click
```

Also, use proper page waits after `.click` and `.navigate` i.e.

```
While i.Busy Or i.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

So, have that proper wait between .navigate and the attempt to click the button and again after clicking the button.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response, it's running but getting "Run time Error '424' : Object required', once i press Debug button it open the New Project Tab.

Comment: getting a problem?

Comment: so add a delay before the click line of Application.Wait Now + Timeserial(0,0,2)